# Showing standard gizmos in editor mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider, unity3d-editor, sceneview

I'm writing an extension to Unity editor and was wondering if there's a way to show multiplbe gizmos for rescaling/moving colliders in the scene view while in editing mode? I don't want to re-invent the wheel and create custome gizmos (already started my ugly version!)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are speaking about [Handles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handles.html).

In the docs are examples on how t use them e.g. [Handles.PositionHandle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handles.PositionHandle.html), [Handles.RotationHandle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handles.RotationHandle.html) and [Handles.ScaleHandle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handles.ScaleHandle.html).

Usually you should use them in [OnSceneGUI](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.OnSceneGUI.html).

```
Vector3 newPosition = Handles.PositionHandle(currentPosition, Quaternion.identity);
Quaternion newRotation = RotationHandle(currentRotation, position);
Vector3 newScale = ScaleHandle(currentScale, position, rotation, handleSize);
```

---

However I would always recommend to rather use proper [`SerializedProperty`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty.html) to avoid problems with Undo/Redo and marking things dirty + saving etc.

Just an example (this won't override the Transform's default handles so it can get confusing)

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(Transform), true, isFallback = false)]
public class TransformEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty position;
    private SerializedProperty rotation;
    private SerializedProperty scale;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        position = serializedObject.FindProperty("m_LocalPosition");
        rotation = serializedObject.FindProperty("m_LocalRotation");
        scale = serializedObject.FindProperty("m_LocalScale");
    }

    private void OnSceneGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();

        position.vector3Value = Handles.PositionHandle(position.vector3Value, Quaternion.identity);
        rotation.quaternionValue = Handles.RotationHandle(rotation.quaternionValue, position.vector3Value);
        scale.vector3Value = Handles.ScaleHandle(scale.vector3Value, position.vector3Value, rotation.quaternionValue, 1);

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just learnt about **Handles** Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: The docs say "Do not use the serializedObject inside OnSceneGUI or OnPreviewGUI. Use the target property directly in those callback functions instead." (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor-serializedObject.html) - so is this really valid code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean this one:

[image]

Or you mean gizmos for your own composite colliders?